# Php check duplicate values in an array

Tags: php

I have a question about arrays.

I have made an array of id's.

The array looks a little like this.

```
$iIds[0] = 12  
$iIds[1] = 24  
$iIds[2] = 25  
$iIds[3] = 25  
$iIds[4] = 25  
$iIds[5] = 30
```

Now i need code to see if any of the values are in the array multiple times.
Then, if the value is in the array 3 times, inject the value into another array.

I tried using array_count_values() , but it returns with the values as keys.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$iIds[0] = 12  
$iIds[1] = 24  
$iIds[2] = 25  
$iIds[3] = 25  
$iIds[4] = 25  
$iIds[5] = 30
$counts = array_count_values($iIds);
$present_3_times = array();
foreach($counts as $v=>$count){
    if($count==3)//Present 3 times
        $present_3_times[] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Count values
2. Filter array
3. flip the array back to how you want it

   $cnt = array_count_values($iIds);

   $filtered = array_filter( $cnt, create_function('$x', 'return $x == 3;'));

   $final = array_flip($filtered);

or

```
array_flip(array_filter( array_count_values($iIds), create_function('$x', 'return $x == 3;')));
```

See: http://codepad.org/WLaCs5Pe

**Edit**

If there are chance of multiple values in the final array, i would recommend instead of flipping the filtered array, just use array_keys, so it would become:

```
$cnt = array_count_values($iIds);

$filtered = array_filter( $cnt, create_function('$x', 'return $x == 3;'));

$final = array_keys($filtered);
```

See: http://codepad.org/ythVcvZM

Answer (score 1):

For create array unique use `array_unique` php function and then for rearrange keys of array use `array_values` php function as given below.

```
$iIds[0] = 12 ;
$iIds[1] = 24 ; 
$iIds[2] = 25 ;
$iIds[3] = 25 ; 
$iIds[4] = 25 ;
$iIds[5] = 30 ;


$unique_arr = array_unique($iIds);
$unique_array  = array_values($unique_arr);

print_r($unique_array);
```

**For getting an array of values are come 3 time in array as duplicate value**

```
$iIds[0] = 12 ; 
$iIds[1] = 24 ;
$iIds[2] = 25 ;
$iIds[3] = 25 ;
$iIds[4] = 25 ;
$iIds[5] = 30 ;

$arr =  array_count_values($iIds);

$now_arr = array();
foreach($arr AS $val=>$count){
   if($count == 3){
      $now_arr[] = $val; 
   }
 }
 print_r($now_arr);
```

thanks

Comment: He doesn't want unique values from an array, he wants to match those values which appear 3 times. Array unique would "match" those that appear 2 times as well, so it's no good.