# PHP - checking for duplicate values in an array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

The values in this array are inserted by pulling XML values (using the simplexml_load_file method) and a foreach loop.

```
$skuArray(2, 4, 3, 7, 7, 4, 1, 7, 9);
```

After populating the array, I then need to check to see if any duplicate values exist in the array (IE, 7 and 4 in this case). Product->sku contains the skuArray value (from an XML file) in the foreach loop below. The code below isn't working. Any advice? Thanks!

```
foreach($XMLproducts->product as $Product) {
if (in_array($Product->sku, $skuArray, > 1) {
// execute code
}
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the duplicated? remove? store? count?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php check duplicate values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155946/php-check-duplicate-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get the number of times a value occurs and then check to see if it is more than one

```
$skuArray = array(2, 4, 3, 7, 7, 4, 1, 7, 9);
$dupes = array_count_values($skuArray);    
foreach($XMLproducts->product as $Product) {
  if ($dupes[$Product->sku] > 1) {
    // execute code
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This code should work, but for some reason it isn't. Perhaps because using the simplexml_load_file method may not be pulling a numeric value to test in the if statement (if > 1).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the duplicates then you can use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
<?php
$input = array(4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3);
$result = array_unique($input);
// $result = array(4, 3)
?>
```

If you need only check if there are duplicates then you can do it using [`array_count_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
<?php
$input = array(2, 4, 3, 7, 7, 4, 1, 7, 9);
$counts = array_count_values($input);
$duplicates = array();
foreach($counts as $v => $count){
    if($count > 1)
        $duplicates[] = $v;
}
```

Then you will have an array `$duplicates` with the duplicated values.

**Source:** [`Php check duplicate values in an array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155946/php-check-duplicate-values-in-an-array)

Comment: Thanks! This code should work, but for some reason it isn't. Perhaps because using the simplexml_load_file method may not be pulling a numeric value to test in the if statement (if > 1).

Comment: Are you sure that the format of the array is like `array(2, 4, 3, 7, 7, 4, 1, 7, 9)`? [`Here`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f82fdd24b10ab6b23fd0f0971163e7a63cdd7710) you can see this code working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has typo:

```
if (in_array($Product->sku, $skuArray, > 1) {
```

in_array expect the first parameter the needle, but you mentioned "Product->sku contains the skuArray value ", anyway, it should be like this:

```
if (in_array($Product->sku, $skuArray)) {
```